# use refresh_token to create access_token

Tags: refresh-token

I want to create access_token using refresh_token with this code.

```
<script>

var client_id = "55227237342xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var client_secret = "-2xxxxxxxxxHB";
var refresh_token= "1/3xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx";
var grant_type = refresh_token;

$.ajax({
    url:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    method:"POST",
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{client_id:client_id, client_secret:client_secret, refresh_token:refresh_token, grant_type:grant_type},
    success:function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);   
    }
});
```

But I am getting this error:

> {error: "unsupported_grant_type", error_description: "Invalid
>   grant_type: "}

**Can Anyone Help!**

Comment: RTM: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#offline

Comment: i am creating web app. in PHP and i m using HTTP/REST method as explained in this doc:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: No, you aren't using it as explained there. `grant_type=refresh_token` is missing.

Comment: still getting this error:
error: "unsupported_grant_type"
error_description: "Invalid grant_type: 1/34.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-JKODNY"

Comment: You have to use your grant_type var, not the refresh_token...

Comment: yes i've added grant_type var in my ajax data but still this error occur